# Passing a callback function and creating an Observable from it

Tags: javascript, callback, rxjs

I cannot create a new Observable object out of the callback function, for example converting `glob` function to Observable stream:

```
const stream$ = fromCallback(() => glob('src/**/*.ts'));
const fromCallback = (cbWrapper) => {
  const cb = cbWrapper();
  const args = cb.arguments;
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    args.push((err, data) => {
      if(err) {
        observer.error(err);
      } else {
        observer.next(data);
      }
      observer.complete();
    });
    cb.call(null, args);
};
```

This is more or less what I want to do - create a `fromCallback` function which accepts my function in a wrapper, adds a new parameter which is a callback handler, and calls observer based on the results. But it doesn't work - the `cbWrapper()` returns always `true` for some reason.

What's wrong here? Is there a better solution to solve this?

Comment: Isn't [`bindCallback`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback) or [`bindNodeCallback`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindNodeCallback) already doing what you want?

Comment: True, I didn't know this function, thanks!